# PyGame, How to draw image into rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

I have rectangles representing blocks in a game I am making. I know how to fill the rectangles with solid colours but how would I fill it with an image?

Comment: Why not just have an image instead? load an image and display it

Comment: Because to test a game you don't need the final graphics, just the hitboxes for objects

Comment: thanks, that was really obvious, I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 2):

To render an image with PyGame you need to first load that image, then blit it to the screen at the specified coordinates.

The coordinates can continue to be the rects you're using for testing (if appropriate), or they can just be a pair of `(x, y)` coordinates for the topleft corner of the image.

```
pygame.Surface.blit(your_image, the_screen, rect_or_coordinates)
```

There are other optional arguments you can pass, but these are all you need to actually display the image once it has been loaded.

The PyGame website has some code for a module named `spritesheet.py` which I use to just take care of the loading boilerplate code. It then gives you a spreadsheet that is a PyGame `Surface`. A quick Google search should point you right at the suggested code.